# MongoDB count occurances with group and unwind

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB database with the following document structure:

```
{
    "name": "ServiceA",
    "areas": ["X", "Y", "Z"],
    "tags": [
        {
            "name": "Financial",
            "type": "A"
        },
        {
            "name": "Consumer",
            "type": "B"
        }
    ]
}
```

There's many entries each with the same structure. Containing the same areas.

There's many predefined tag names, sorted into a few types.

The aim is to group by area and then count the number of occurrences of each tag. So an output like this:

```
{
    "area": "X",
    "count": 100, // Total entries with X as an area
    "tagNameCount": {
        "Financial": 20,
        "Consumer": 10,
        ...
    },
    "tagTypeCount": {
        "A": 70,,
        "B: 40
    }
}
```

I've been starting of using `$unwind` on areas, but it's the next steps from there I'm stuck on. I get that I need to use `$group`, but I can't work out how to count occurrences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/index.html) operator which allows perform several aggregation in one.

### Walkthrough

```
1. We $unwind by area and tags
2. With $facet, we perform 3 parallel aggregations:
  2.1 We count unique areas
  2.2 We count unique tag names for each area
  2.3 We count unique tag type for each area
3. We join 2 parallel arrays by flatten areas
4. We assemble desired output
```

---

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$areas"
  },
 {
    $unwind: "$tags"
  },
  {
    $facet: {
      areas: [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$areas",
            count: {
              $addToSet: "$_id"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            area: "$_id",
            count: {
              $size: "$count"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      tagNameCount: [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: {
              name: "$tags.name",
              areas: "$areas"
            },
            count: {
              $addToSet: "$_id"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$_id.areas",
            tagNameCount: {
              $push: {
                k: "$_id.name",
                v: {
                  $size: "$count"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $addFields: {
            tagNameCount: {
              $arrayToObject: "$tagNameCount"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      tagTypeCount: [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: {
              type: "$tags.type",
              areas: "$areas"
            },
            count: {
              $addToSet: "$_id"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$_id.areas",
            tagTypeCount: {
              $push: {
                k: "$_id.type",
                v: {
                  $size: "$count"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $addFields: {
            tagTypeCount: {
              $arrayToObject: "$tagTypeCount"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$areas"
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "tagNameCount": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$tagNameCount",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$areas.area",
              "$$this._id"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "tagTypeCount": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$tagTypeCount",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$areas.area",
              "$$this._id"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      area: "$areas.area",
      count: "$areas.count",
      tagNameCount: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$tagNameCount.tagNameCount",
          0
        ]
      },
      tagTypeCount: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$tagTypeCount.tagTypeCount",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      area: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zriXcciyP_I)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one method:

- unwind both areas and tags
- for each area collect the applicable tags, and the unique names and types
- count the names to get the total number of tags
- for each unique name, count the matching values in the tags
- do the same for each unique type
- project out the unique fields

```js
    db.collection.aggregate([
      {$unwind: "$areas"},
      {$unwind: "$tags"},
      {$group: {
          _id: "$areas",
          names: {$push: "$tags.name"},
          uniqueNames: {$addToSet: "$tags.name"},
          types: {$push: "$tags.type"},
          uniqueTypes: {$addToSet: "$tags.type"}
        }},
      {$addFields: {
          count: {$size: "$names"},
          names: {
            $arrayToObject: {
              $map: {
                input: "$uniqueNames",
                as: "needle",
                in: {
                  k: "$$needle",
                  v: {
                    $size: {
                      $filter: {
                        input: "$names",
                        cond: {$eq: ["$$this","$$needle"]}
          }}}}}}},
          types: {
            $arrayToObject: {
              $map: {
                input: "$uniqueTypes",
                as: "needle",
                in: {
                  k: "$$needle",
                  v: {$size: {
                      $filter: {
                        input: "$types",
                        cond: { $eq: [ "$$this","$$needle"]}
      }}}}}}}}},
      {
        $project: {
          uniqueNames: 0,
          uniqueTypes: 0
      }}
    ])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QtkNBaLUwC8)